# Function "d::~d" not defined when setting breakpoint by GDB

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb, breakpoints

I'm using gdb to debug in Linux. But when I set the breakpoint like this `b d::~d`, the console returns:

> Function "d::~d" not defined

I can't set breakpoint in the destructor.
Here is the sample code:

```
class b
{
  protected:
   ...
  public:
  b(){
  ...
  }
  ~b() {
  ...
  }
  ...
} ;

class d: public b{ 
  protected:
  ...
  public:
  d(){
  ...
  }
  ~d() {
  ...
  }
  ...
  p* get(){...};
} ;
```

However, I set breakpoints of b::b, b::~b and d::d successfully.
After I type in 'i b', the console returns:

> breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000577a6c in d::get() at ../x.h:65

The line number is right, but the function name is wrong.

Comment: have you tried making the destructor virtual? this may be not the reason but it's still a potential error having a non-virtual destructor .

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason, I can't do that now.@Hayt

Comment: Not sure why you're not able to `b d::~d`, but you may try setting breakpoint on a particular line number of a particular file

Comment: also: have you compiled with optimization? maybe this function got optimized out for some reason.

Comment: I have updated my question.@alexeykuzmin0

Comment: I'm not sure of optimization. Is there any other possible reasons?@Hayt

Comment: Does the ~d contain any lines?  Could it have been optimized out? Do an nm on the executable and take a look.  Just do a simple compile with no -O flag to avoid optimization oddities during debugging

Comment: Yes, some delete inside it.@MatthewFisher

Answer (score 0):

What if you will rewrite it like this?

```
class b
{
  protected:
   ...
  public:
  b(){
  ...
  }
  virtual ~b() {
  ...
  }
  ...
} ;

class d: public b{ 
  protected:
  ...
  public:
  d(){
  ...
  }
  ~d() {
  ...
  }
  ...
  p* get(){...};
} ;
```